# TableView Cell doesn't reset subviews with constraints that were added for reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently, I'm implementing a comment feature for my app. Each comment represent a single cell in the tableview. However, there are also replies for the comments. For the replies, I create a a new UiView() and constrain it to the bottom of the comment. If I have another reply, I constrain that to the bottom of the previous reply.

So in the end, comments that have several replies will have several UiViews created and constrained in that cell.

The problem is, when I scroll, the constraints that was used in the previous cells seem to get reused. Is there a way I can clear all previous constraints when the cell is being reused?

Comment: Implement the `prepareForReuse` method in your cell subclass. In this method you need to remove any views you have added.

Comment: @Paulw11 Then do you think it is a good idea to store all the added views for that cell. For example:

var addedViews = [UIView]()
Then, in prepareForReuse, just remove all those views?

Comment: Yes, you need to do something like that so that you can remove them easily.

Comment: I have a similar question. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454149/implement-a-comment-and-reply-view-like-instagram)